# Open file from terminal in already running "pure data" instance

Tags: command-line, terminal, xdg-open

Whenever I `xdg-open patch.pd` it will open a new pure data instance, how can I make it open with existing instance?

Comment: I don't know anything about it, but I guess it's about this: https://puredata.info/

Comment: well, I think this is relevant for any app that doesn't automatically handles opening files in currently running instances.

Comment: No, it's highly program specific. I don't see [any options](https://puredata.info/docs/manuals/pd/x3.htm#s4) that would enable this behaviour.